# css3 stacking contexts and 3d transformations

Tags: css, transform, z-index

Consider the following situation:

HTML:

```
<div class="container-outer">
    <div class="container-inner">
        <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvas3"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container-outer,
.container-inner,
canvas {
    position: absolute;
}

canvas {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.container-outer {
    perspective: 1000px;
    transform-style: flat;
}

.container-inner {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#canvas1 {
    z-index: 1;
}
#canvas2 {
    z-index: 2;
}
#canvas3 {
    z-index: 3;
}
```

As I understand it, every single one of these HTML elements creates a new stacking context, since they are all positioned. Given this, I would expect #canvas3 to always appear on top of #canvas1 and #canvas2. If every single element creates its own new stacking context, those contexts get stacked per DOM order, as if they were each just a simple stacking layer, right?

This all works fine until I apply a 3d transformation to #canvas3, for example,

```
#canvas3 {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.773673421825969, 0.551819872491575, -0.311326620582756, 0, -0.392059934956964, 0.802962743707314, 0.448931887505848, 0, 0.497713214373135, -0.225267974957394, 0.837577396839813, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

(That's just an arbitrary rotation.) At this point, parts of #canvas3 intersect with and slip behind #canvas2 and #canvas1. What I need is for #canvas3 to be abel to undergo whatever arbitrary transformations I apply to it, but always render in front of #canvas2 and #canvas1. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Being positioned alone does not cause an element to establish a stacking context. If it's positioned, its computed z-index must not be auto for it to establish a stacking context. That being said, yes, every single one of these elements does establish its own stacking context - the reason `.container-outer` does is because of its `perspective` property, and `.container-inner` its `transform-style` property. Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with 3D transforms to be able to post an answer, so I'm leaving this as a comment.

Comment: Thanks, @BoltClock. I may have solved my problem by swapping the `transform-style` properties, putting `preserve-3d` on `.container-outer` and `flat` on `.container-inner`. We'll see if that breaks my project in any other ways, but it seems to be working alright so far ...

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wcLw26qj/. Generally if you want to make sure a 3d-transformed element is rendered above other elements you can distance it from the elements behind it by translating it away in the z-axis.